# Where can I view the expiration date of a Microsoft Teams meeting recording?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I see in MS teams recordings an expiration warning:

[image]

Where can I view the expiration date of a Microsoft Teams meeting recording? I didn't see it after clicking on `here`.

I read on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/meeting-expiration one may view the default value and change it on https://admin.teams.microsoft.com:

[image]

But I'm not an admin:

> You don't have access to the Teams admin center. The account credentials you used to sign in aren't authorized to access this website. Make sure you're using the right account and that you have correct permissions. Learn more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to click on [image: IMG:] to see the expiration date:

[image]